# Vote Fu Rails App voting link help

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, voting

I'm having some trouble using the Vote Fu plugin for Rails 3.  So far, I've got all the voting features worked out (I can have Users vote for Articles successfully in the rails console).

The problem that I am having is that I cannot seem to get a link working on the front end. I have the following in my Articles view so that Users can hopefully just click on a link to vote for the particular Article.

```
    <%= link_to image_tag('up.gif', :size => '50x50'), upvote_article_path(article), :method => put %>
```

When I try to run my app, I get an error that says:

SQLite3:: SQLException: no such column: score: SELECT SUM(score) AS sum_id FROM "votes" WHERE ("votes.voteable_id = 4 AND "votes".voteable_type = 'Article'

Does anyone have any advice on this matter?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your table is not setup properly, try `rake db:migrate`. Did you use vote_fu's migration generator? Make sure you are using the rails 3 version if using rails 3 [available here](https://github.com/vshvedov/vote_fu_rails_3).

According to the docs:

### Create vote_fu migration

**Create a new rails migration using your new vote_fu generator (Note: "VoteableModel" is the name of the model on which you would like votes to be cast, e.g. Comment): rails g vote_fu VoteableModel**

**Run the migration: rake db:migrate**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I ran that already and it didn't work. I'm still having problems with my table.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share a copy of your db/schema.rb file (just the Articles table), the Articles Controller, and the Gemfile (the vote_fu line)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y191ENKf

My Gemfile has nothing about vote_fu in it.  Could this be the problem? 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes. This is a problem, and it explains how your migration may not be generating properly. Your rails environment must be aware of vote_fu in order to properly generate the code needed for migrations. If this is not fixed, let me know and I can further assist.